# Once per browser session cookie

Tags: javascript

i have this popup code that activates once the user closes the browser window. The problem is that i have pics on my site so every time a surfer clicks on a picture it is like he's taken away from the site and the popup is shown.

i'd like to make this popup to show just once per browser session.

```
var sync = true;
window.onbeforeunload = doSync;

function doSync() {
if (sync == true) {
window.open('myurl', '_blank');
}
else {
return;
}
}
```

So... what code should I place to make a once-per-browser-seession cookie?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are for storing data you want sent to the server with every *REQUEST* so don't use cookies at all for this, use [*sessionStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)

```
var sync = true;
window.onbeforeunload = doSync;

function doSync() {
    if (sync && !window.sessionStorage.getItem('popupShown')) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('popupShown', 1);
        window.open('myurl', '_blank');
    }
}
```

Where *popupShown* is the flag in *sessionStorage* designating that it's happened before.

Comment: Paul S  thank you for this. I've made a few tests and it seem to work and do what I need.

Comment: Just as a comment for anyone using this and being a novice like me: try not to use target blank for pages on the same site since sessionStorage will consider this a being a new instance and open another popup and it can be irritating.